# Using Python 3 to import multiple excel workbooks and sheets into single data frame

Tags: python, excel, pandas, glob, worksheet

I am still learning python. I am trying to import multiple workbooks and all the worksheets into one data frame.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import os #checking the working directory 
print(os.getcwd())

all_data = pd.DataFrame() #creating an empty data frame
for file in glob.glob("*.xls"): #import every file that ends in .xls
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    all_data = all_data.append(df, ignore_index = True)

all_data.shape #12796 rows with 19 columns # we will have to find a way to check if this is accurate
```

I am having real trouble finding any documentation that will confirm/explain whether or not this code imports all the data sheets in every workbook. Some of these files have 15-20 sheets

Here is a link to where I found the glob explanation: http://pbpython.com/excel-file-combine.html

Any and all advice is greatly appreciated. I am still really new to R and Python so if you could explain this in as much detail as possible I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Does the data in all sheet and files have same columns and structure

Comment: yes! They all have the same structure/order/data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is importing all the sheets in the workbook.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import os #checking the working directory 
print(os.getcwd())

all_data = pd.DataFrame() #creating an empty data frame
rows = 0
for file in glob.glob("*.xls"): #import every file that ends in .xls
    # df = pd.read_excel(file).. This will import only first sheet
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(file)
    sheets = xls.sheet_names # To get names of all the sheets
    for sheet_name in sheets:
        df = pd.read_excel(file, sheetname=sheet_name)
        rows += df.shape[0]
    all_data = all_data.append(df, ignore_index = True)

print(all_data.shape[0]) # Now you will get all the rows which should be equal to rows
print(rows)
```

Comment: Thank you, I ran this code, and I recieved the following:

    WARNING *** OLE2 inconsistency: SSCS size is 0 but SSAT size is non-zero.

It looks like the columns have been switched around. There still are 19 columns. 

It also looks like there are fewer rows than before. The previous version had 12k+ rows, this time there are 7k.

Comment: That's not an error message but just a log message that always appears in traces and anyways you can suppress it. Have you printed the last two lines? and are their values same?

Comment: The last two lines print as follows: 7303 and 334562. Do you have a reference I use to read up on? I am guessing that there are rows of all Nulls?

Comment: Do a little more research on the sheets data why this is happening. You can go through https://www.quora.com/Can-I-save-multiple-Excel-sheets-by-using-Python-Pandas-to-CSV?share=c033ca22&srid=uyDvF . Go through more sites